# How to create aliases in c#

Tags: c#, aliases

How do i create aliases in c#

Take this scenario

```
class CommandMessages
{
   string IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1;
}
```

say i create an object of this class

```
CommandMessages objCommandMessage = new CommandMessages();
```

To  i need to write lengthy string

```
objCommandMessage.IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1
```

every time i access the variable, this is a pain as i am using this variable as a key for a dictionary.

```
Dict[objCommandMessage.IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1]
```

therefore i should be able to do something like this

```
Dict[str1]
```

where str1 is alias for objCommandMessage.IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1, How do i do it?

Comment: Ow... I hope those UPPERCASED names are caused by interop...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create another, shorter, property that references the original one?

```
class CommandMessages
{
    string IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1;

    public string Str1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following anywhere you like:

```
Dict[objCommandMessage.Str1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string str1 = objCommandMessage.IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1;
```

Comment: Is it an alias? If i modify str1 will it reflect in IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1 ????

Answer (score 2):

```
public string str1 { get { return objCommandMessage.IDS_SPEC1_COMPONENT1_MODULE1_STRING1; } }
```